# date Column conversion in pandas

Tags: python

My data looks like this

Date     Value

0
2009-01 30

1
2009-02 25

2
2009-03 23

3
2009-04 27

4
2009-05 38

train.info()

RangeIndex: 84 entries, 0 to 83
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Date     84 non-null object
Value    84 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1.4+ KB

data type is shown as object but while i am trying to convert to date time getting an error
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 train['Date']= pd.to_datetime(train['Date'])

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `Date` column has missing values, you can do like this:

```
train['Date']= pd.to_datetime(train['Date'], errors='coerce')
```